# How to hide a div after some time interval?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code is

```
    <div class="sendStatus" ng-if="reportSent">
      <span data-icon="ok"></span> 
      {{progressStatus}}
    </div>
```

The idea is show this div when the report is sent, meaning `reportSent` is true. Now I would also like to hide this dive after `2 seconds` lets say. How to I do that?

Answer (score 5):

`$timeout` can be used to hide the div after a delay

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.sendReport = function() {
    $scope.reportSent = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.reportSent = false;
    }, 2000);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <button ng-click="sendReport()">send report</button>
  <div class="sendStatus" ng-if="reportSent">Report Sent</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) (a dependency you inject into your controller).

Example:

```
$scope.reportSent = true;
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.reportSent = false;
}, 2000);
```